# HTML application drop down - from an array of folders

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, hta

I've got an HTML application, where I want users to select a folder from a drop-down list.

To populate this drop-down list, I would need the application to check for all folders in a directory and list those folders in the drop-down list.

Is this possible with JavaScript or VB Script?

Comment: A folder list on their own machine? You can use WSH if it is an hta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the answer myself anyway.  Here's an example for anybody else wanting to do this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="divcontainersub">
    <label for="folder">Select Folder:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <select id="folder" class="inputfields" tabindex="1" name="folder" size="1" style="width:278px;"">
            <option value="0">Select a folder...</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

**VB (within the Window_OnLoad Sub):**

```
Dim oFSO, oFolder, oSubFolder, i, oNewOption
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("\\Server\Share")
Set oSubFolder = oFolder.SubFolders

For Each i in oSubFolder
    Set oNewOption = window.document.CreateElement("OPTION")
    oNewOption.Text = i.Name
    oNewOption.Value = i.Name
    Folder.Add(oNewOption)
Next
```